# Why does ld need -rpath-link when linking an executable against a so that needs another so?

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, ld, rpath

I'm just curious here. I have created a shared object:

```
gcc -o liba.so -fPIC -shared liba.c
```

And one more shared object, that links against the former one:

```
gcc -o libb.so -fPIC -shared libb.c liba.so
```

Now, when creating an executable that links against `libb.so`, I will have to specify -rpath-link to ld so it can find `liba.so` when discovering that `libb.so` depends on it:

```
gcc -o test -Wl,-rpath-link,./ test.c libb.so
```

otherwise ld will complain.

Why is it, that ld MUST be able to locate `liba.so` when linking `test`? Because to me it doesn't seem like ld is doing much else than confirming `liba.so`'s existence. For instance, running `readelf --dynamic ./test` only lists `libb.so` as needed, so I guess the dynamic linker must discover the `libb.so -> liba.so` dependency on its own, and make it's own search for `liba.so`.

I'm on an x86-64 GNU/Linux platform, and the main()-routine in `test` calls a function in `libb.so` that in turn calls a function in `liba.so`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Why is it, that ld MUST be able to locate `liba.so` when linking `test`? Because to me it doesn't seem like ld is doing much else than confirming `liba.so`'s existence. For instance, running `readelf --dynamic ./test` only lists `libb.so` as needed, so I guess the dynamic linker must discover the `libb.so -> liba.so` dependency on its own, and make it's own search for `liba.so`.

Well if I understand linking process correctly, *ld* actually does not need to locate even `libb.so`. It could just ignore all unresolved references in `test` hoping that dynamic linker would resolve them when loading `libb.so` at runtime. But if *ld* were doing in this way, many "undefined reference" errors would not be detected at link time, instead they would be found when trying to load `test` in runtime. So *ld* just does additional checking that all symbols not found in `test` itself can be really found in shared libraries that `test` depend on. So if `test` program has "undefined reference" error (some variable or function not found in `test` itself and neither in `libb.so`), this becomes obvious at link time, not just at runtime. Thus such behavior is just an additional sanity check.

But *ld* goes even further. When you link `test`, *ld* also checks that all unresolved references in `libb.so` are found in the shared libraries that `libb.so` depends on (in our case `libb.so` depends on `liba.so`, so it requires `liba.so` to be located at link time). Well, actually *ld* has already done this checking, when it was linking `libb.so`. Why does it do this checking second time... Maybe developers of *ld* found this double checking useful to detect broken dependencies when you try to link your program against outdated library that could be loaded in the times when it was linked, but now it can't be loaded because the libraries it depends on are updated (for example, `liba.so` was later reworked and some of the function was removed from it).

**UPD**

Just did few experiments. It seems my assumption *"actually ld has already done this checking, when it was linking `libb.so`"* is wrong.

Let us suppose the `liba.c` has the following content:

```
int liba_func(int i)
{
    return i + 1;
}
```

and `libb.c` has the next:

```
int liba_func(int i);
int liba_nonexistent_func(int i);

int libb_func(int i)
{
    return liba_func(i + 1) + liba_nonexistent_func(i + 2);
}
```

and `test.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int libb_func(int i);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", libb_func(argc));
    return 0;
}
```

When linking `libb.so`:

```
gcc -o libb.so -fPIC -shared libb.c liba.so
```

linker doesn't generate any error messages that `liba_nonexistent_func` cannot be resolved, instead it just silently generate broken shared library `libb.so`. The behavior is the same as you would make a static library (`libb.a`) with *ar* which doesn't resolve symbols of the generated library too.

But when you try to link `test`:

```
gcc -o test -Wl,-rpath-link=./ test.c libb.so
```

you get the error:

```
libb.so: undefined reference to `liba_nonexistent_func'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Detecting such error would not be possible if *ld* didn't scan recursively all the shared libraries. So it seems that the answer to the question is the same as I told above: *ld* needs *-rpath-link* in order to make sure that the linked executable can be loaded later by dynamic loaded. Just a sanity check.

**UPD2**

It would make sense to check for unresolved references as early as possible (when linking `libb.so`), but *ld* for some reasons doesn't do this. It's probably for allowing to make cyclic dependencies for shared libraries.

`liba.c` can have the following implementation:

```
int libb_func(int i);

int liba_func(int i)
{
    int (*func_ptr)(int) = libb_func;
    return i + (int)func_ptr;
}
```

So `liba.so` uses `libb.so` and `libb.so` uses `liba.so` (better never do such a thing). This successfully compiles and works:

```
$ gcc -o liba.so -fPIC -shared liba.c
$ gcc -o libb.so -fPIC -shared libb.c liba.so
$ gcc -o test test.c -Wl,-rpath=./ libb.so
$ ./test
-1217026998
```

Though *readelf* says that `liba.so` doesn't need `libb.so`:

```
$ readelf -d liba.so | grep NEEDED
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
$ readelf -d libb.so | grep NEEDED
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [liba.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

If *ld* checked for unresolved symbols during the linking of a shared library, the linking of `liba.so` would not be possible.

Note that I used **-rpath** key instead of **-rpath-link**. The difference is that *-rpath-link* is used at linking time only for checking that all symbols in the final executable can be resolved, whereas *-rpath* actually embeds the path you specify as parameter into the ELF:

```
$ readelf -d test | grep RPATH
 0x0000000f (RPATH)                      Library rpath: [./]
```

So it's now possible to run `test` if the shared libraries (`liba.so` and `libb.so`) are located at your current working directory (`./`). If you just used *-rpath-link* there would be no such entry in `test` ELF, and you would have to add the path to the shared libraries to the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file or to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

**UPD3**

It is actually possible to check for unresolved symbols during linking shared library, `--no-undefined` option must be used for doing that:

```
$ gcc -Wl,--no-undefined -o libb.so -fPIC -shared libb.c liba.so
/tmp/cc1D6uiS.o: In function `libb_func':
libb.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `liba_nonexistent_func'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Also I found a good article that clarifies many aspects of linking shared libraries that depend on other shared libraries: 
[Better understanding Linux secondary dependencies solving with examples](http://www.kaizou.org/2015/01/linux-libraries/).

Comment: Learnt a lot. Thanks. The link isn't working anymore though.

Comment: @SurajeetBharati the link should be fixed once my edit is approved (basically, replace the final slash with `.html`)

Comment: I can't access the link right now, it's available at archive.org though: https://web.archive.org/web/20161025105929/http://www.kaizou.org/2015/01/linux-libraries.html

Answer (score 11):

I guess you need to know when to use `-rpath` option and `-rpath-link` option.
First I quote what `man ld` specified :

> 2. The difference between -rpath and -rpath-link is that directories specified by -rpath
>      options are included in the executable and used at runtime, whereas
>      the -rpath-link option is only effective at link time. Searching
>      -rpath in this way is only supported by native linkers and cross linkers which have been configured with the --with-sysroot option.

You must distinguish between link-time and runtime. According to your accepted anton_rh's answer, checking for undefined symbols is not enabled when compiling and linking shared libraries or static libraries, but ENABLED when compiling and linking executables. (However, please note that there exist some files which are shared library as well as executables, for example, `ld.so`. Type `man ld.so` to explore this, and I don't know whether or not checking for undefined symbols is enabled when compiling these files of "dual" kinds).

So `-rpath-link` is used in link-time checking, and `-rpath` is used for link-time and runtime because `rpath` is embedded into ELF headers. But you should be careful that `-rpath-link` option will override `-rpath` option during link-time if both of them are specified.

But still, why `-rpath-option` and `-rpath` option? I think they are used for eliminating "overlinking". See this [Better understanding Linux secondary dependencies solving with examples.](http://www.kaizou.org/2015/01/linux-libraries.html), simply use `ctrl + F` to navigate to contents related to "overlinking". You should focus on why "overlinking" is bad, and because of the method we adopt to avoid "overlinking", the existence of `ld` options `-rpath-link` and `-rpath` is reasonable: we deliberately omit some libraries in the commands for compiling and linking to avoid "overlinking", and because of omitting, `ld` need `-rpath-link` or `-rpath` to locate these omitted libraries.

Comment: You wrote "But still, why '-rpath-option'", but I think you meant '-rpath-link' there, but I cannot edit this currently due to too many pending edits.

Answer (score 7):

You system, through `ld.so.conf`, `ld.so.conf.d`, and the system environment, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, etc.., provides the **system-wide** library search paths which are supplemented by installed libraries through `pkg-config` information and the like when you build against standard libraries. When a library resides in a defined search path, the standard library search paths are followed automatically allowing all required libraries to be found.

There is no standard **run-time library search path** for custom shared libraries you create yourself. You specify the search path to your libraries through the `-L/path/to/lib` designation during compile and link. For libraries in non-standard locations, the library search path can be optionally placed in the header of your executable (ELF header) at compile-time so that your executable can find the needed libraries.

`rpath` provides a way of embedding your custom run-time library search path in the ELF header so that your custom libraries can be found as well without having to specify the search path each time it is used. This applies to libraries that depend on libraries as well. As you have found, not only is the order you specify the libraries on the command line important, you also must provide the run-time library search path, or rpath, information for each dependent library you are linking against as well so that the header contains the location of **all** libraries needed to run.

**Addemdum from Comments**

> My question is primarily why ld must "automatically try to locate the
>   shared library"  (liba.so) and "include it in the link".

That is simply the way `ld` works. From `man ld` "The -rpath option is also used when locating **shared objects which are needed by shared objects** explicitly included in the link ... If -rpath is not used when linking an ELF executable, the contents of the environment variable "LD_RUN_PATH" will be used if it is defined." In your case `liba` isn't located in the `LD_RUN_PATH` so `ld` will need a way locating `liba` during the compile of your executable, either with `rpath` (described above) or by providing an explicit search path to it.

> Secondarily what "include it in the link" really means. To me it seems
>   that it just means:  "confirm it's existence" (liba.so's), since
>   libb.so's ELF headers are not modified (they already had a NEEDED tag
>   against liba.so), and the exec's headers only declare libb.so as
>   NEEDED. Why does ld care about finding liba.so, can it not just leave
>   the task to the  run-time linker?

No, back to the semantics of `ld`. In order to produce a **"good link"**, `ld` must be able to locate **all** dependent libraries. `ld` cannot insure a good link otherwise. The runtime linker must **find and load**, not just to **find** the shared libraries **needed by a program**. `ld` cannot guarantee that will happen unless `ld` itself can **locate all needed shared libraries** at the time the progam is linked.

Comment: Yes, but the -rpath-link option doesn't insert any RPATH tags in any of the object files. The documentation says:


When using ELF or SunOS, one shared library may require another. This happens when an ld -shared link includes a shared library as one of the input files. When the linker encounters such a dependency when doing a non-shared, non-relocateable link, it will automatically try to locate the required shared library and include it in the link, if it is not included explicitly. In such a case, the -rpath-link option specifies the first set of directories to search

Comment: And I guess linking an executable is a "non-shared, non-relocateable link". My question is primarily why ld must "automatically try to locate the shared library" (liba.so) and "include it in the link". Secondarily what "include it in the link" really means. To  me it seems that it just means: "confirm it's existence" (liba.so's), since libb.so's ELF headers are not modified (they already had a NEEDED tag against liba.so), and the exec's headers only declare libb.so as NEEDED. Why does ld care about finding liba.so, can it not just leave the task to the run-time linker?

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually telling ld (when linking `libb` against `liba`) *where* `liba` is - only that it's a dependency. A quick `ldd libb.so` will show you that it cannot find `liba`.

Since presumably these libraries are not in your linker search path, you will get a linker error when you link the executable. Keep in mind that when you link liba itself, the function in libb is *still* unresolved, but `ld`'s default behavior is not to care about unresolved symbols in DSOs until you link the final executable.