# How do I set DT_RPATH or DT_RUNPATH?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ld

On Linux, the `ld.so(8)` man page discusses the search order for dynamic libraries. It says that `DT_RPATH` is deprecated, and also mentions `DT_RUNPATH`. There is no mention of the `-rpath` linker option.

The `ld(1)` man page mentions the `-rpath` and `-rpath-link` options, but never mentions `DT_RPATH` or `DT_RUNPATH` except in a describing the library search order, which of course does not match the information given in `ld.so(8)`.

Finally there is an `LD_RUN_PATH` environment variable. `ld(1)` says it used if the `-rpath` and `-rpath-link` options are not set, but `ld.so(8)` does not mention it.

My intuition is that `-rpath` actually sets `DT_RPATH`, and `-rpath-link` sets `DT_RUNPATH`, but I cannot find this confirmed anywhere. I have always used `-rpath`; if it is the same as `DT_RPATH` than I should not use it, but the how-to articles I've found on dynamic linking say to use it, so I'm not sure it's the same.

Could someone clarify how `DT_RPATH` and `DT_RUNPATH` are set, and whether they are the same as `-rpath` and `-rpath-link`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are **compiling** a program, you create object files and then **link** them together. You may use GNU ld(1) to link them, there are also other linkers, LLVM linker. A linker combines object files into executable. GNU ld(1) is part of binutils with [documentation available here](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/).

When you **execute** an already compiled ready to use executable then the dynamic linker ld.so(8) finds the libraries on the system that the executable depends on, loads them and executes the executable. ld.so(8) is a shared library usually distributed as part of C standard library, usually on linux that's glibc, but there are also other, like musl.

I think it's confusing that both these programs are named "linker". One is like "compiling linker" and the other is "executable linker".

> How do I set DT_RPATH or DT_RUNPATH?

Edit the elf file to include specific section.

When creating the elf file with GNU ld, nowadays you set RUNPATH section with `-rpath=something`. You can set `RPATH` section with `--disable-new-dtags -rpath=something`. RPATH is deprecated, so normally `-rpath` sets RUNPATH. https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/1127068.html *This does not check out on my system and I have to compile with `gcc -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath=/tmp` to set RUNPATH...

You can also set sections in any ELF file after compilation. See [Can I change 'rpath' in an already compiled binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769141/can-i-change-rpath-in-an-already-compiled-binary)

> whether they are the same as -rpath and -rpath-link?

From [ld documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.36/ld/Options.html#Options):

> The difference between -rpath and -rpath-link is that directories specified by -rpath options are included in the executable and used at runtime, whereas the -rpath-link option is only effective at link time.

And the documentation also explains how `-rpath-link` works. It's to specify directories for searching dependent shared libraries.

> Finally there is an LD_RUN_PATH environment variable

When **compiling** an executable GNU ld(1) also searches libraries in directories specified in this variable.

Answer (score 3):

The `-rpath` command line option used to create a `DT_RPATH` entry in the `.dynamic` section, but since `DT_RPATH` was deprecated in favor of `DT_RUNPATH`, modern linker versions use `DT_RUNPATH` instead. This means that using `-rpath` on a really old linker, you will create a dynamic section entry with `.d_val = DT_RPATH`, but if your linker is up to date, you will create one with `.d_val = DT_RUNPATH` instead.

The `-rpath-link` option is an option which *does not* create any entry, but is used to supersede the `DT_RUNPATH` entry present in the dynamic section of a library that is being linked. Therefore, when compiling, you should usually not need it. You can find more information on [`man 1 ld`](https://manned.org/ld.1) (scroll down to `-rpath-link=`) or in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35748179/3889449).

Comment: so, what is the DT_ means? I can only see (RUNPATH) by ```readelf -d xxx.so``` instead of 'DT_RUNPATH'

Comment: @vrqq that's because `readelf` shows you a more human-friendly name instead of the `#define` used for the dynamic tag, `DT` stands for "dynamic tag". The full name of the constant would be `DT_RUNPATH` which is really just the number `29`. See [`man 5 elf`](https://manned.org/elf.5) section "Dynamic tags (Dyn)".