# Compiling dynamically linked library in a makefile

Tags: c, linux, gcc, dll, makefile

I am trying to run my library using a make file. I currently have a dynamic library called libname.so which I created by linking the object files of some of my C files. This library works correctly when I run the following lines of code in my linux shell :

```
   gcc -L. main1.c -lname -o out
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

But when I copy these exact lines of code in to a make file and name the make file title for this function 'names' and then run 'make names' in linux shell, I get the following error:

```
./out: error while loading shared libraries: libname.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then once again when I run the final two lines of code shown at the end of the makefile function again then run the out file, it is fixed and the program works again.

I just need to figure out how to make it work directly from the makefile.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your makefile builds `out` correctly, but when you try to run `out` you get a run-time error because... the working directory is not in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? If that's the problem, then you cannot fix it from within the makefile. A process is not allowed to modify environmental variables of the process that invoked it, so Make cannot modify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the shell in which you run Make.

Comment: Yes you have understood correctly. Is there anything I can do during the building of the library file or anything at all which will fix my issue ?

Comment: `-L.` Is your library `libname.so` in the same folder as your source file? If not, you may want to change the library path from `.` to actual path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> ```

These two lines do not influence the creation of the program in any way because you type the lines **after** creating the program.

These lines are not used for building your program, but they influence running the program (by typing `./out`).

If you compile your program using `gcc` directly (not using `make`) and open a new terminal, you also have to type these two lines (again) before you run the program.

It does not matter how you build the program (by typing `gcc` manually or by running `make`):

After opening a new terminal, you will need to type these two lines before you run the program.

However, the dynamic linker does not only use the path information from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but also from the `DT_RUNPATH` information in the executable.

Unlike the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable which is set on one console (or terminal) only, the `DT_RUNPATH` information is stored directly in the executable file.

As described in [another question on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67131565/how-do-i-set-dt-rpath-or-dt-runpath), you can set the `DT_RUNPATH` information using the `-Wl,-rpath=<value>` switch:

```
gcc -L. main1.c -lname -o out -Wl,-rpath=.
```

If you do this, the dynamic linker will search your library (`libname.so`, if I understand correctly) in the current directory.

Note:

`.` really means: In the current directory; it does not mean: In the same directory as the executable file!

If your program is stored in the directory `./somedir` and you type `somedir/out`, the file `./libname.so` is searched, not the file `./somedir/libname.so`.

This is both the case for the `-Wl,-rpath=` method and for the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=` mehtod.